# OpenCL barrier usage within conditional

Tags: opencl, barrier

According to the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/barrier.html):

> If barrier is inside a conditional statement, then all work-items must enter the conditional if any work-item enters the conditional statement and executes the barrier.
>
> If barrier is inside a loop, all work-items must execute the barrier for each iteration of the loop before any are allowed to continue execution beyond the barrier.

In my understanding this means, that in any Kernel:

```c
if(0 == (get_local_id(0)%2)){
  //block a
  work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
  //block a part 2
}else{
  //block b
  work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
  //block b part 2
}
//common operations
```

Should one worker reach `//block a`, every other worker needs to reach it too.

By this logic it is not possible to correctly synchronize every odd local worker with every even one ( blocks a and b ) to be run at the same time.

Is this understanding correct?

What would be a good synchronisation strategy for a situation like this ?

- where every other worker would need to do a different logic, but by `//block a part 2` and `//block b part 2` the workers inside one working group be synced up.
- in the requested usecase there are more phases, than 2, and I'd like to keep every phase to be synchronised.

Would a logic like this be an acceptable solution?

```c
__local number_finished = 0;
if(0 == (get_local_id(0)%2)){
  //block a
  atomic_add(&number_finished, 1);
  while(number_finished < get_local_size(0));
  //block a part 2
}else{
  //block b
  atomic_add(&number_finished, 1);
  while(number_finished < get_local_size(0));
  //block b part 2
}
work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
//common operations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By this logic it is not possible to correctly synchronize every odd local worker with every even one ( blocks a and b ) to be run at the same time.
>
> Is this understanding correct?

It is not possible. When using a `work_group_barrier`, you must ensure all work-items in the work group reach it. If there are paths within your code that don't reach the barrier, it may lead to undefined behavior.

> What would be a good synchronization strategy for a situation like this ?

Usually, barriers are used outside of any conditional sections / loop:

```
if (cond)
{
   // all work items perform work that needs to be synchronized later 
   // such as local memory writes
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // note the CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE flag

// now every work item can read the data the other work items wrote before the barrier. 

for (...)
{
}

barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
```

> Would a logic like this be an acceptable solution?

It might work, but a barrier outside the conditional section would be more efficient than a busy wait.

```
if(0 == (get_local_id(0)%2)){
  //block a
}else{
  // block b
}
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE); // ensures number_finished == get_local_size(0)
```

Comment: I might add, that in my requested usecase I would need to synchronise inside blocks a and b as well. I will update my question with this.

Comment: a key concept I expanded the question with is that the workers would do different operations based on `get_local_id(0)` , but in multiple phases(more, than one), and I'd like to keep them synchronised between phases

Comment: I think the best solution would be to have barriers, but not under conditionals. I was thinking of it because of your answer, so I accepted it; thank you!